# Emberjs learning resources

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to learn EmberJS. It has a very steep learning curve.

I have watched Tuts Plus' "Let's learn Ember", Peepcodes Fire up EmberJS.
But, I still don't feel like learning much.

I wonder if anyone could point out any good learning resources for EmberJS?

Comment: CodeSchool just put out a pretty nice course that covers the basics.https://www.codeschool.com/courses/warming-up-with-emberjs

Comment: Check out the bottom of the tag wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info

Comment: [11 Ember.js resources to get you started](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/11/11-emberjs-resources-to-get-you-started)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://emberwatch.com/ - for watching ember videos and tutorials

http://ember101.com/ - other ember video tutorial site

http://www.manning.com/skeie/ -excellent book for learning more about ember (highly recommend)

https://github.com/discourse/discourse -- look at this open source ember project. it's huge, but can help you learn how things work and how to structure code

http://www.quora.com/Ember-js/What-is-the-best-way-to-learn-Ember-js -- there's also more answers to this question on here. Hope that helps.